# How to provide a 3D border to a UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimageview, border

I want to provide a 3D just like the image posted here.[image]

How can I do that?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Before Shah's answer
![enter image description here][2]

After his answer
![enter image description here][3]

Comment: Hey there! Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

using coreGraphics use shadow. sample code for shadow is.

one imageview span entire view on viewcontroller.

in .h file @property  CGContextRef context;

```
    #define radians(degrees) (degrees * M_PI/180)
      -(void) JustForYouShadow
 {
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.jpg"];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

[self.imgView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    //shadow for iBeacon
     CGSize  myShadowOffset = CGSizeMake (0.9,  15);
     CGContextSaveGState(context);
     CGContextSetShadow (context, myShadowOffset, 10);

     CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(10,10,150,150);

     CGContextTranslateCTM( context, 90, 80 ) ;
     CGContextRotateCTM(context, radians(30));

     CGContextDrawImage(context, rectangle, image.CGImage);
     CGContextStrokePath(context);
     CGContextRestoreGState(context);
//get line on image
self.imgView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[self.imgView setAlpha:1.0];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 }
```

[image]

it's running fine, this is screen snap of simulator.

Comment: what is Context here?

Comment: in sort drawing area, CGContextRef

Comment: So what Should I actually put in place of Context?

Comment: wait for couple of minute , i'll modify my answer with complete example.

Comment: Will it take much time?

Comment: i have modified my answer try this.

Comment: Its not working at all I am attaching the screenshot before and after your answer. Please check it out

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look at it and suggest the remedies for it.

Comment: :- Did you find any other solution for the problem as it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: i have modified my answer just check

Comment: You are understanding the whole concept as a wrong notion. I have achieved the shadow effect. Only thing I want to achieve is the 3D border width on the left and the bottom of the Image view.